# Elasticsearch nested aggregation with multi conditions

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm a newbie on Elasticsearch, using 7.10. there is a problem confusing me sereval days. I'm doing a questionnaire system with some statistic function, and also need low processing time, Elasticsearch is my choice.

the problem: I'd like to do answer filter which can get aggregation data, something like "how many people choose A in qeustion 1 and also choose B in question 2?"

Here is the mapping

```json
{
  "some_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "answers": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "answer": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 2048
                }
              }
            },
            "subject": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

here are some questionnaire data inside

```json
{
    answers: [
        {"subject": "sbj_a", "answer":["ans_01", "ans_02"]},
        {"subject": "sbj_b", "answer":["ans_11", "ans_12"]},
        {"subject": "sbj_c", "answer":["ans_21", "ans_22"]}
    ]
},
{
    answers: [
        {"subject": "sbj_a", "answer":["ans_02", "ans_03"]},
        {"subject": "sbj_b", "answer":["ans_11", "ans_13"]},
        {"subject": "sbj_c", "answer":["ans_23", "ans_22"]}
    ]
}
```

I want to see how many people choose ans_02 or ans_03 in sbj_a, and choose ans_11 in sbj_b.

here is my aggregation, but something wrong.

```json
{
    "size":0,
    "aggs":{
        "subjects":{
            "nested":{
                "path":"answers"
            },
            "aggs":{
                "subjects":{
                    "terms":{
                        "field":"answers.subject"
                    },
                    "aggs":{
                        "answer_dist":{
                            "terms":{
                                "field":"answers.answer.keyword"
                            },
                            "aggs":{
                                "answer_dist":{
                                    "terms":{
                                        "field":"answers.subject"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it return s

```json
{
  .....
  "aggregations": {
    "subjects": {
      "doc_count": 230431,
      "subjects": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 123364,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "sbj_a",
            "doc_count": 10711,
            "answer_dist": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": "ans_01",
                  "doc_count": 7959,
                  "answer_dist": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                      {
                        "key": "sbj_a",
                        "doc_count": 7959
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "key": "ans_02",
                  "doc_count": 2033,
                  "answer_dist": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                      {
                        "key": "sbj_a",
                        "doc_count": 2033
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                .....(more)
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I expected receiving the second aggregation with sbj_02 data, but it wasn't, is any advice?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED.

I do query first that find `sbj_a` with `ans_02` or `ans_03` and `sbj_b` with `ans_11` or `ans_12`, also see answer distribution by aggregation

```json
{
  "size":0,
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must":[
        {
          "nested":{
            "path":"answers",
            "query":{
              "bool":{
                "must":[
                  {
                    "term":{
                      "answers.subject":"sbj_a"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "bool":{
                      "should":[
                        {
                          "term":{
                            "answers.answer.keyword":"ans_02"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "term":{
                            "answers.answer.keyword":"ans_03"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested":{
            "path":"answers",
            "query":{
              "bool":{
                "must":[
                  {
                    "term":{
                      "answers.subject":"sbj_b"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "bool":{
                      "should":[
                        {
                          "term":{
                            "answers.answer.keyword":"ans_11"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "term":{
                            "answers.answer.keyword":"ans_12"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term":{
            "status":"OK"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs":{
    "subjects":{
      "nested":{
        "path":"answers"
      },
      "aggs":{
        "answer_dist":{
          "terms":{
            "field":"answers.answer.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```